# DelegatingHandler SendAsync Change RequestUri before sendRequest

Tags: c#, http, httprequest, asp.net-web-api

I try to make a gateway that take a request then map request url to configuration patterns and change request uri to that new pattern, it works fine localHost but when i change patterns to domain names it returns 404

```
protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync
         (HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    request.RequestUri = GetForwardToURL(request.RequestUri);
    if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Get || request.Method == HttpMethod.Trace)
        request.Content = null;
    return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
}
```

// Example uri = "http://myproxy.com/api-1/..."

// patterns "api-1" = "http://myproxy2.com"

```
public Uri GetForwardToURL(Uri uri)
{
    var section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("patterns") as NameValueCollection;

    foreach (var key in section.Keys)
    {
        if (uri.OriginalString.Contains(key.ToString()))
        {
            return new Uri(new Uri(section[key.ToString()]), uri.PathAndQuery);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Better show the code for `Get New host name with keeping the query paramaters`.

Comment: @MarcelN. I Edit it and add my custom method for setting uri

Comment: The reason you get a 404 is most likely that you're building the new URL wrong. If we could see `GetForwardToURL` then we'll be able to say what/if something goes on in there.

Comment: @MarcelN. I already add GetForwardToURL Code ..